# issue in using navigation for ionic application in web view

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am using ionic 3 and I am facing problem in navigation of the ionic app in the web view, specially for the using back button.

I know that it has solution in ionic 4, but my app is in  ionic 3.

Also, the browser doesn't track the history of the ionic app, so maybe I am facing problem because of that. How to solve this issue of navigation in ionic 3?

Comment: Which kind of Navigation issue you are facing ? not able to understand your issue

Comment: @CodeChanger I am facing issue for routing while using ioic for browser , when I am hitting back button in the app it takes to the home page , 

but in app that back button is working fine , but in web it takis to the home page

Comment: means its working in both case back button taking to home page than what is the issue in Navigation ?

Comment: @CodeChanger yes

Comment: still not clear that issue is that your web app redirect to home page which it should not redirect to Home page right ?

Comment: @CodeChanger yes  home page  should not redirect to Home page, it should go the the last past which I have visited before this page

Comment: Can you add some code of navigation which will redirect you to home page ?

Answer (score 0):

try using lazy loading

example
 `this.navCtrl.push('OtherPage');` 
instead of 
`this.navCtrl.push(OtherPage);`

this will show the current page you are at in the `url` only limiting factor is when the browser refreshes it loses the `back button` in the app but you can navigate back to the previous pages through the `browsers back button`.